# React-intl, Redux-Form combine and raise warnings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I try to use React and Redux for now. and I'm now making i18n App so I have to use React-intl package in this project.
Now My login form is like this. and import is like below.

```
import React, {
  Component
} from 'react';
import {
  reduxForm
} from 'redux-form';
import {
  injectIntl
} from 'react-intl';
```

now, I would like to use `intl.formatMessage` so I have to use `injectIntl` into this Component like

```
export default injectIntl(LoginForm);
```

and now I don't get any errors.
Also, I would like to use Redux-form into my login name form and e-mail form in it. like

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'loginForm',
  fields: ['name', 'password']
})(LoginForm);
```

I need the both, so I combine them into 1 export, like

```
export default reduxForm({
  form: 'entrance',
  fields: ['name', 'password']
})(injectIntl(LoginForm));
```

or

```
export default injectIntl(reduxForm({
  form: 'entrance',
  fields: ['name', 'password']
})(LoginForm));
```

But both type of above I've got a warning

```
warning.js:44Warning: Unknown props `initialValue`, `autofill`, `onUpdate`, `valid`, `invalid`, `dirty`, `pristine`, `active`, `touched`, `visited`, `autofilled` on <input> tag. Remove these props from the element. For details, see "abbred"
in input (created by TextField)
in div (created by TextField)
in TextField (created by Entrance)
in div (created by CardText)
...
```

I can use both of them with this warning, but how do I would like to get rid of this warning.
How should I do?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to update Redux-Form to v6 to overcome these errors (assuming you're running React v15.2.0+). Run:

```
npm install --save redux-form@6.0.0-rc.3
```

You will also need to change how you're using Redux-Form due to major changes in its infrastructure. Take a look at the documentation here:
http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-rc.3/docs/MigrationGuide.md/

Also, this tutorial has code samples that demonstrate how a Redux-Form v6 setup should look: http://davidmeents.com/create-redux-form-validation-initialized-values/